# Why do I get errors while trying to insert a new node to a list

Tags: c++, list, struct, header, stack

I have a header that declares a stack and a list.
I am trying to add a node of stuck into the list but I fail to do so.
Can someone help me figure out why this function doesn't work?

****both these codes are declerations in headers***

```
/* a link that contains a positive integer value*/
struct link
{
    int value;
    struct link *next;
};
```

---

```
typedef struct link link;

typedef struct
{
    link *head;
} linkedList;

/* a positive-integer value stack, with no size limit */
typedef struct stack
{
    int count;
    int maxSize;
    bool empty;
    linkedList* list;
} stack;
```

Now what I'm trying to do is this:

```
void add(linkedList *list, int newValue)
{
    linkedList* temp = list;


    while (temp->head)
    {
        temp->head = temp->head->next;
    }


    temp->head->next->value = newValue;   //<---- this line is making the error
}

// add new link in the beginning of list with newValue in it
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doesn't work". Can you explain what it does and what you expect it to be doing? 

One obvious problem is the fact that your `while` loop ends when `temp->head` is `NULL` and then in the very next statement after the `while` loop you try to use `temp->head->next` i.e. `(NULL)->next`. This is problematic. Similarly, you set `temp1` to `NULL`, never modify it in the `while` loop, and then try to access `temp1->head` i.e. `(NULL)->head`. You can check all this if you run your program in a debugger.

Comment: doesnt work means that every time i try to put another link inside the list that is inside the stack doesnt work it gives me an error messege and shows me that the sub head parameters (value) and (next) cant be read in the memory
but as for what you said earlier  sure i can remove the temp1 but what do i do with the while?

Comment: Please add the exact error message (i.e. copy-and-paste) into the question.

Comment: What line of code causes the error?

Comment: error msg Unhandled exception at 0x00E84600 in Exercise 1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

I edited it in the code (last 1) Neli Kirk

Comment: What are the values of `temp->head->next->value` in order.. are any null or look uninitialized?

Comment: well there list was suppose to have the numbers 1-5 in each head the purpose of that function is to add the numbers into the value parameter and then create a new link on the *next* and from there to put the nubmer after that on the new value integer

Comment: the last link will always point to null btw

Answer (score 0):

In `add`, you're currently modifying `temp->head` to walk it through the list. `temp` is a local variable, but it points to the real linked list, so when you assign to `temp->head`, it's modifying the structure of the list itself.

I'd guess your real intent was something more like:

```
void add(linkedList *list, int newValue)
{
    link *temp = list->head;

    while (temp->next != nullptr)
        temp = temp->next;

    link *node = new node;
    node->next = nullptr;
    node->value = newValue;
    temp->next = node;
}
```

For a stack, however, you don't need (or want) to traverse the list before adding the new item.

```
void add(linkedList *list, int newValue) {
    link *node = new link;
    node->next = list->head;
    node->value = newValue;
    list->head = node;
}
```

As always, though, think twice about using a linked list (if you have any choice). At least in my experience, it's *rarely* a really useful data structure (especially in a case like this where you're storing small items--on a typical 64-bit implementation, each node will be a 32-bit int and a 64-bit pointer, so you're using twice as much space for pointers as for the data itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Jerry Coffin it works great (hopefully I would be able to understand my mistake there) but trust me when I tell you this : I didnt have any choice :(

Comment: but if I could just ask you another question...
how do I erase a link after I made one?

Comment: @TotalyNotUbisoft: The usual is to try to keep one question...one question. If you have another question, go ahead and post another question.